# Optimize Fragment Shader

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I want to optimize the fragment shader performance. Currently my fragment shader is

```
fragment half4 fragmen_shader_texture(VertexOutTexture vIn [[stage_in]],
                                       texture2d<half> texture [[texture(0)]]){

    constexpr sampler defaultSampler;

    half4 color =  half4(texture.sample(defaultSampler, vIn.textureCoordinates));


    return color;
}
```

The task of this is to return the texture color. Anyway to optimize more than this.

Comment: If you are not sampling to render at a different texture size, would using a compute shader (With A8 or newer devices only) and calling read() instead of sample() help with performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No options for optimizing the fragment shader AFAICT, it's doing virtually nothing other than sampling the texture. However, depending on your situation, there still might be scope for optimization by:

- Reducing bandwidth usage by using a more compact texture format (565 or 4444 instead of 8888, or better still 4-bit or 2-bit PVRTC).
- Making sure that alpha blending is disabled if alpha blending is not required.
- If the texture has lots of 'empty space' (e.g. think particle texture with a central circular blob and blank corners) then you could make sure the geometry fits it more tightly by rendering it as an Octagon rather than as a quad for instance.
- Enable mipmapping if there's any possibility the image can be minimized. Disable more expensive mipmapping options like trilinear/anisotropic filtering.

Comment: Reducing Bandwidth of Texture. I am using kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA. For me Alpha information is important. What texture format I can use for Optimization. Since Alpha important disabling Alpha blending is not possible.

Comment: 4444 is a 16bpp format with an alpha channel, and PVRTC 4bpp/2bpp can have an alpha channel. You're likely going to be able to notice the reduced precision though, especially if you're dealing in 2D rather than 3D.